# Unable to open camera using cv2.VideoCapture(0) in Docker Ubuntu host

Tags: python, docker, opencv

```
import cv2

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _,frame=cam.read()
    if frame is not None:
        cv2.imshow("frame",frame)

cam.release()
```

This is my code running for camera capture. I have runned an ubuntu image in which i have installed opencv using apt install python3-opencv.

It gives an error:

```
global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (887) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
```

Comment: How did you start the container?  Docker is an isolation system and in general containers can't directly access host hardware devices; is there a specific reason to run this in Docker and not a Python virtual environment?

Comment: @DavidMaze 
docker run ubuntu
docker run -ti --device /dev/video0:/dev/video0 pradyumn10/ubuntu-python3 /bin/bash

Answer (score 4):

check if you using `--device` flag correctly. This is how I would run it :

```
docker run -it --rm --env="DISPLAY" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" --device="/dev/video0:/dev/video0" test:0.1 python ./test_camera.py
```

You also need to provide `--env="DISPLAY" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw"` for docker to connect to the screen. Before running docker, use this command `xhost local:docker` to give access for the docker user group to use the screen.

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend checking the device path using `ls -ltrh /dev/video*` as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/348842/1164227). The path of the device I wanted to use was `/dev/video0`. Then I added a flag with an appropriate device path `--device /dev/video0` just after `docker run`. In particular, if you are creating a jupyter-notebooks directory you can write:

```
docker run --device /dev/video0 --gpus all -it -p 8888:8888 -v [directory-path]:/tf [image-name]
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
xhost local:docker
sudo docker run -it --rm --privileged --env="DISPLAY" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" --device="/dev/video0:/dev/video0" ubuntu:latest
```

To check that the camera is working (change video0 with your device):

```
ffplay /dev/video0
```