# Docker Container: ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, opencv, flask, deep-learning

I have a deep learning project that uses flask . I want to put it in docker container but when I launch the container it display this error in web :

**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.**

and this is the log of the container :

```
2024-03-18 11:55:14 [2024-03-18 10:55:14,583] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
2024-03-18 11:55:14 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-03-18 11:55:14   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
2024-03-18 11:55:14     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2024-03-18 11:55:14                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-03-18 11:55:14   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
2024-03-18 11:55:14     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2024-03-18 11:55:14          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-03-18 11:55:14   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
2024-03-18 11:55:14     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2024-03-18 11:55:14          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-03-18 11:55:14   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
2024-03-18 11:55:14     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
2024-03-18 11:55:14            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-03-18 11:55:14   File "/app/process/app.py", line 20, in capture_route
2024-03-18 11:55:14     capture_frame(path_name)
2024-03-18 11:55:14   File "/app/process/f_capture.py", line 4, in capture_frame
2024-03-18 11:55:14     import cv2
2024-03-18 11:55:14 ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2024-03-18 11:55:14 172.17.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2024 10:55:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
```

Keeping in mind I have a `requirements.txt` file that has all package.

I tried re-installing all the packages but no luck.

this is the dockerfile :

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.12.2

# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . .

# Make port 5000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 5000

# Run the command to start your application
CMD cd process && flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: `requirements.txt` lists _Python_ package dependencies. libGL is a C dependency -- it needs to be installed with your OS package manager (rpm/yum/apt/pkg/etc), not with pip or other Python-specific tools.

Comment: To know which package manager to use, and thus for anyone to be able to write an answer that goes a different route than your own answer went, we would need to see the Dockerfile -- at minimum, enough of it to identify the distro and the package manager it uses.

Comment: ok i will check it out but i got the camera error now .

Comment: Right, but the camera is a different question. We only solve one problem per question -- that way questions stay narrow and focused.

Comment: For the benefit of folks reading this, `python:3.12.2` resolves to `python:3.12.2-bookworm` and is thus Debian-based on non-Windows systems. (There are also `-alpine` variants, but those aren't default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is i added this package to requirements.txt file :

**opencv_python_headless**

> but now i have a camera error :

```
[ WARN:0@0.008] global cap_v4l.cpp:997 open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
[ERROR:0@0.008] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:159 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range
```

Comment: As a hint for the problem opening the camera: How, if at all, are you plumbing the video device through to the container? Are you running the container in privileged mode?

Comment: (To explain _why_ your solution works, the headless version of OpenCV doesn't _need_ libGL; but you also could have fixed the problem by correctly installing libGL into the container).

Comment: no i'am not unning the container in privileged mode . should i do ?

Comment: Might be necessary. Privileged mode removes the mask on which syscalls can be invoked; if interacting with the video device involves syscalls or ioctls that aren't allowlisted for privileged mode with the specific version of Docker you're running, that could be your problem.

Comment: (mind, you also need to be actually bind-mounting the device into the container; if you haven't done that yet -- and you aren't showing your Dockerfile or the command-line invocation of Docker so we don't know -- it needs to happen first).

Comment: i added the dockerfile , check it out

Comment: Okay, I had to go look it up at https://hub.docker.com/_/python, but python:3.12.2 is Debian-based, so it would be `apt-get install libgl1` to install libGL to make the non-headless package to be able to load its libraries (or at least, _that_ library).

Comment: The Dockerfile isn't doing anything to set up a bind mount for `/dev/video0`, but you could possibly be doing that at invocation time -- you aren't showing us, so we don't know.

Comment: For your follow-up question, see [How do I get webcam access permissions in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62081881/how-do-i-get-webcam-acess-permissions-in-docker)

Comment: ...or, better, [unable to open camera using cv2.videocapture() in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929645/unable-to-open-camera-using-cv2-videocapture0-in-docker-ubuntu-host) -- note the answer suggesting `--device` to explicitly plumb through the individual device node.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).